# ActionName Attribute & UrlHelper.Action Method in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use the ActionName Attribute for enabling a dash in the URL:

```
[ActionName("My-Action")]
public ActionResult MyAction() {
    return View();
}
```

It works fine. But it don't work when I generate links for the navigation-menu:

```
Link = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext).Action(MVC.Area.Controller.MyAction())
```

The generated Link on the Website is always without the dash.

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: By what you have posted I believe that it is being generated through the default route and not the named one. Have you tried something as `.Action("My-Action")`? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dime2lo: Thank you for your tip! It works with: `.Action("My-Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area"})`